# Setting expires header for a specific URI?

Tags: apache, configuration

I'm trying to set expire header for a specific URI but for some reason it is not working, what I've done so far in the httpd.conf file was the following:

```
<LocationMatch "/mysite/contentservices/weather/get.json">
  ExpiresDefault A86400
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "/mysite/*">
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
</LocationMatch>
```

This simply does not work for me. I get no expiry date headers for the contents I specified.  I also don't understand what exactly happens when you have two `LocationMatch` directives that overlap that the first one takes precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but the docs do not mention LocationMatch as possible context.

"Context:   server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Answer (score 2):

I assume that /mysite/contentservices/weather/get.json is a static data file and NOT served up by CGI / mod_php / something else?

The configs are applied in the order in which they are found in the config file.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html

Although given no other factors the different formatting of the argument shouldn't be a problem, it might be worth checking what happens if you try:

```
<LocationMatch "/mysite/contentservices/weather/get.json">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</LocationMatch>
```

C.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the LocationMatch brackets.

Alternatively: Some proxy servers remove the expires-header.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Do yo mean he should put the get.json after the /mysite/* or something else?